# Conways proof of every interval is a connected set

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So I'm following through Conways proof that every interval is connected. I'll rewrite the proof up until where I'm stuck for context.

Proof: Suppose $X = [a,b]$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $A \subset X$ be an open subset of $X$ such that $a \in A$ and $A\neq X$. Since $A$ is open and $a \in A$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $[a,a+\epsilon) \subset A$. Let $$r = \sup\{\epsilon: [a,a+\epsilon) \subset A\}$$

Claim: $[a,a+r) \subset A$. In fact, if $a \leq x < a+r$ then, setting $h = a+r-x>0$ the definition of supremum implies there is an $\epsilon>0$ with $r-h<\epsilon<r$ and $[a,a+e) \subset A$.

From here on out the proof is very straightforward to follow, but why does the definition of supremum imply that there is an $\epsilon$ such that $r-h<\epsilon<r$? Can someone explain this step. For reference this is prop 2.2 is Conways functions of one complex variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A supremum $ r $ of a set $ S $ has two properties: it is an "upper bound" ($ r \geq x $ for all $ x \in S $), and *it is the smallest upper bound*.  Another way to phrase this property of suprema (at least suprema of bounded non-empty sets) is to say that for all $ h > 0 $ there exists $ \varepsilon \in S $ which is greater than $ r - h $.  Indeed, if that weren't the case, then $ r - h $ would be a smaller upper bound of $ S $, contradicting the definition of supremum.

Comment: Gah I knew it was staring me right in the face, yeah that tracks thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since the number $r-h=x-a$ is strictly smaller than the supremum $r$ of the set $E:=\{\epsilon>0\mid[a,a+\epsilon)\subset A\},$ it is not an upper bound of $E,$ i.e. there exists some $\epsilon\in E$ such that $r-h<\epsilon.$

But that is not the end of the story: we also want $\epsilon$ to be $<r.$ For this, just notice that if $\epsilon\in E$ then $(0,\epsilon]\subset E,$ which allows us to reduce our $\epsilon$ at will.

Comment: I know that $r-h$ can't be an upper bound, since $r$ is the sup, but by the existence of some $\epsilon$, wouldn't that be an upper bound, or no because we can make it as small as we like?

Comment: ? The existence of elements in $E$ which are larger than $r-h$ equivalent to the fact that $r-h$ is *not* an upper bound of $E!$